# How can I forward odbc/oledbc connection through DMZ

Tags: oracle, odbc, network

I have an Oracle database separated from our BI system by two network zones (different sides of a DMZ). Company policy dictates that firewall openings may only pass to an adjacent zone. Therefore it is not possible for the BI system to directly talk to the Oracle database.

What is the best way to get the information to the BI system? Our enviroment is (almost) entirely Windows-based.

I have thought of adding a server inside the DMZ to forward the data from the Oracle database to the BI system, something like an ODBC/OLEDBC proxy, however I have found no software that does this.

Another solution might be to translate database requests using some kind of Web API, but I have found no such solutions either (other than building it myself, which I would really like to avoid). Is there any such software available for free or purchase?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2060363/odbc-proxy-for-remotely-accessing-legacy-resources There seems to be a patent from Google about this, by the way (most likely invalid for prior art)